# For which $\alpha$ the integral converges $\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{dx\,dy}{(x^2-xy+y^2+1)^\alpha}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

For which $\alpha$ the integral converges $$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{dx\,dy}{(x^2-xy+y^2+1)^\alpha}\,?$$
I changed to polar coordinates but got stuck at after calculating the integral of $r$

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}dt\int_{0}^{n}\frac{r\,dr}{(r^2(1-1/2(\sin(2t))+1)^\alpha}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}dt\frac{((r^2(1-1/2(\sin(2t))+1)^{-\alpha+1}}{2(-\alpha+1)(1-(1/2)\sin(2t)}\big|_{0}^{n}$$ and after i plug the parameters i don't know how to continue .

Comment: You are almost done. What condition need $y^{1-\alpha}$ when $y \rightarrow +\infty$?

Comment: $1-\alpha\geq0$

Comment: Why? in this case it go to infinity.

Comment: Yeah yeah my mistake

Comment: So, if you take reverse, then you find, that your way is finished successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it independent of the angular variable use the following change of coordinates

$$u = \frac{x-y}{\sqrt{2}} \hspace{24 pt} v = \frac{x+y}{\sqrt{2}}$$

with the factor chosen such that the Jacobian is $1$. Then the integral becomes

$$I = 2^\alpha\iint_{\Bbb{R}^2} \frac{du\:dv}{\left(3u^2+v^2+2\right)^\alpha}$$

Tweaking $u$ by the interchange $u \leftrightarrow \sqrt{3}u$ we get the integral

$$I=\frac{2^\alpha}{\sqrt{3}}\iint_{\Bbb{R}^2}\frac{du\:dv}{(u^2+v^2+2)^\alpha}$$

Using polar coordinates at this stage then gives us

$$I = \frac{2^{\alpha+1}\pi}{\sqrt{3}} \int_0^\infty \frac{r}{(r^2+2)^\alpha}dr = \begin{cases} \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}(\alpha-1)} & \alpha > 1 \\ \mbox{Diverges} & \alpha \leq 1 \\ \end{cases}$$

Comment: this change or coordinates respond to something?it looks something like eignvalues maybe?

Comment: @ronkurman it's a $45$ degree rotation.

Comment: Can you give intuition when to you this coordinate

Comment: @ronkurman whenever you see a quadratic with $xy$'s

Comment: Thanks i will try to use it :)